# Jump from PDF line into .Rnw (with Skim)

Tags: pdf, emacs, viewers, sweave, forward-inverse-search

I have a LaTeX document saved as `.Rnw` which I compile with Sweave to get a `.tex` document and finally-once compiled with LaTeX, a PDF.

Now with Skim I can jump from a line in the PDF back into the text editor (in my case Emacs/Aquamacs) at the same point of the text. This function is quite handy since with all the markdowns of a LaTeX document sometime could be hard to proof-read the document directly from source.

I am sure someone already thought about how great would be to jump from the PDF also into a `.Rnw`.

Is there any way to do that or get something close?

Comment: RStudio has done a decent job on this long time ago, and the implementation was not trivial, so good luck with reinventing the wheel in other editors...